# Apache Poi best way

Tags: java, apache-poi, universal

Hi last time I was wondering about good way to save object by Apche Poi.

Way 1

```
List<Something> list = ....;
cell.setValue(obj.getName) etc
```

Way 2
Convert List to Object[]

```
for(int i=0; i<objectsToSave.size;i++){
 for(int y=0; y<object.size;y++){
  if(obj instance of Integer)
   cell.setValue((Integer) obj[i]
  if(obj instance of RichTextString)
   cell.setValue((RichTextString) obj[i]
 }
}
```

In 1 way I don't have if's but if we want to save another object we have to create new "converter".

In 2 way is "universal" but I can have many if's. (I think it's bad practise)

Do you have any idea/ good way for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really isn't a great way of doing this.  One thing you could try to avoid the repeated type-checking is to create a map of setters, like this:

```java
private static Map<Class<?>,BiConsumer<Cell,Object>> typeMap = new HashMap<Class<?>, BiConsumer<Cell,Object>>();

static {
   typeMap.put(Integer.class, obj -> cell.setValue((Integer)obj);
   typeMap.put(String.class, obj -> cell.setValue((RichTextString)obj);
//....and so on
}

public void setCell(Cell cell, Object obj) {
   typeMap.get(obj.getClass()).apply(cell, obj);
}
```

Then your code would become:

```java
for(int i=0; i<objectsToSave.size;i++){
 for(int y=0; y<object.size;y++){
  setCell(cell, object);
 }
}
```

This has the advantage of avoiding the repeated RTTI of `instanceof` but it can be dangerous, in particular you have to be careful to exhaustively check for every class, or throw an exception.

It's still not great, though; all you're doing is, essentially, moving the conditional.